# Prove a time series to be NOT identically independent distributed

Tags: independence, covariance, correlation, time-series

I am trying to prove that this time series (given that $X_{t}$ and $M_{t}$ are iid and independent of each other)
$$
Y_{t} = X_{t}(1-X_{t-1})M_{t}
$$ is not i.i.d, so my understanding is that I need to prove that this series has dependent realizations. **Am I correct by making this statement?**

We know that if two random variables are independent, then their correlation or covariance is 0.

Can I use this strategy by saying that if their correlation or covariance is equal something else which is not 0, then they are dependent?

For example, can I try to show that if $Cov(Y_{t},Y_{t+1}) \ne 0$, then $\{Y_{t}\}$ is not iid?

If not, any tip would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: One has to be careful in  making such a statement. If $X_t \equiv 0$ or $X_t \equiv 1$ or $M_t \equiv 0$ then $(Y_t)$ is i.i.d..

Comment: But your general plan, of using correlation to imply dependence, is good.

Comment: Thanks folks! I appreciate your inputs!